# extract key value pair for aws credential file

Tags: awk

I was wondering how do i extract the value of default_key as below, given that there are 2 aws profiles.?

Input:
/.aws/credentials

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id=email1
aws_secret_access_key=default_key

[personal]
aws_access_key_id=email_2
aws_secret_access_key=_key_2
```

I tried this, but not sure how to get a nested value

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = "secret_access_key=" } ; { print $2 }' .aws/credentials
```

this shows the 2 values of aws_secret_access_key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following. Written with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk -F'=' '
/^\[default\]/{
  found=1
  next
}
found && /^aws_secret_access_key=/{
  print $2
  found=""
}
' Input_file
```